# Finding the volume between cylinders, paraboloid and plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I need to find the volume of the solid between the cylinders
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1,\quad x^{2}+y^{2}=4$$
and limited by
$$ z = 0, \quad  z = 9 - x^2 + y^2  $$

---

i got this far but i dont know if it is right or wrong

$$\iint\int _{0}^{9-x^2-y^2}dzdx dy$$

then turned into polar

$$\int _{0}^{2\pi}\int _1^{2}(9-r^2)r drd\theta$$

i feel like im missing something

Comment: replace $\int _{}^{}\int _{}^{}\int _{0}^{9-x^2-y^2}dzdx dy$ by $\iint_{1\le x^2+y^2\le4}\left(\int_0^{9-x^2-y^2}dz\right)dx dy.$

Comment: Go on! $\int _0^{2\pi}\int _1^{2}(9-r^2)r drd\theta=2\pi\left[9r^2/2-r^4/4\right]_1^2=\dots$.

Comment: $\iint_{1\le x^2+y^2\le4}\dots dxdy\ne\int _{-2}^{2}\int _{\sqrt{1-y}}^{\sqrt{4-y}}\dots dxdy$ (there is a square missing on $y$, and $x$ may also be $<0$). Anyway, better not try to split it, since you'll turn it soon into polar coordinates.

Comment: Thx but If i split what do i get for boundaries

Comment: On a $\iint$ there are no boundaries, there is a domain (here: $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid1\le x^2+y^2\le4\}$, written $1\le x^2+y^2\le4$ for short).

Comment: If you really want to (uselessly) split it, replace  your $\int _{\sqrt{1-y}}^{\sqrt{4-y}}$ by: $\int _{\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}+\int _{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}.$

Comment: The region is cylindrically shaped, so cylindrical coordinates is very, very likely to be the best way to go.

Comment: Well, according to MathSE rules one should avoid this kind of discussion in comments. Watch the first section of the tour: ( cf: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). I still don't understand why not provide an answer if the OP's question standards have been satisfied (a priori). This is just a comment (more) with all due respect, of course.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (as mentionned in the 2nd comment) the answer is contained in it (the OP's "feeling like missing something"  is not justified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right. In fact, if you start directly with cylindrical coordinates, the volume is given by

$$
V = \int_1^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{9-r^2} r \,dz d\theta dr = 2\pi \int_1^2 r (9-r^2)\, dr = 2\pi \frac{39}{4}=\frac{39 \pi}{2},
$$

which is what you obtained.